# Action column doesn't appear in action column in angular materital table

Tags: angular

```
<mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" matSort>

  <ng-container *ngFor="let column of displayedColumns; let i = index" [matColumnDef]="column">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header style="flex: 1">{{ headerLabels[i] }}</th>

    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element" style="flex: 1">    
        {{ element[column] }}
    </td>    
  </ng-container>
  <ng-container matColumnDef="action">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Action </th>   
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let user "> 
      <button mat-raised-button >Edit</button> 
    </td>
  </ng-container>
  <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns; sticky: true"></mat-header-row>
  <mat-row *matRowDef="let user; index as i; columns: displayedColumns" (click)="redirectToManageUsers(user.id)"></mat-row>

</mat-table>
```

but on screen edit icon is not coming up ,its shows blank.  here is the .ts file code .

```
 displayedColumns: string[] = ['firstName', 'lastName', 'userName', 'vendorName', 'actions'];
  headerLabels: string[] = [
    'First Name',
    'Last Name',
    'User Name',
    'Vendor Name',
    'Action'
  ];
```